# Using conversation workspace directly without virtual agent in middle

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-virtual-agent

I am using the  chat javascript below  and its working very well with script that I created at virtual-agent.watson.ibm.com  -only problem is the pre configured answers that I try to disable/delete all  because of I prefer defining my custom chatscripts in my own workspace.

I would prefer to use ONLY my own custom chat script workspace that I have created at https://www.ibmwatsonconversation.com/eu-gb/

Question: What do I need to change in javascript below to make it connect directly to the watson service , CONVERSATION module,  and skip whole example content at virtual-agent.watson.ibm.com  that is not easy to get rid of.

```
script src='https://unpkg.com/@watson-virtual-agent/chat-widget/dist/chat.min.js'></script>

  var config = {
    el: 'ibm_chat_root',
    baseURL:  'https://api.ibm.com/virtualagent/run/api/v1', 
    botID: 'IKNOW e',
    XIBMClientID: 'YES
    XIBMClientSecret: YES
  };
  window.IBMChat.init(config);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use Watson Conversation and not Watson Virtual Agent. Just follow this https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple

There is plenty of documentation on using Watson Conversation here:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/index.html